I'm 17 and someone 33 photographed me without my consent when I was walking at a park. Can I press charges?
I'm 17 years old. Someone 33 photographed me without my consent when I was walking at a park. I stopped him and asked him to delete the photos. I told him 8 times about it, but he ain't listening to me. Can I press charges for him invading my privacy?
Photographing and/or recording anyone without their consent is a felony punishable by up to 7 years in prison and $50,000 in fines, plus additional restitution.

This needs more detail: was it one picture of the park and you just happened to be in it, or did he specifically take pictures of you?

What jurisdiction?

Re-read the exact wording of the law that makes it a felony. You will find that it is a crime only where the person being photographed has an expectation of privacy.

united-states

I'm 17 and someone 33 photographed me without my consent when I was
walking at a park. Can I press charges?

No. This is perfectly legal.

Photographing and/or recording anyone without their consent is a
felony punishable by up to 7 years in prison and $50,000 in fines,
plus additional restitution.

I'm not aware of any jurisdiction where this is the case. Did you just make this up?
If the photograph is used for commercial purposes, without your consent, you may be entitled to sue for the amount of basically a modeling fee, under a legal doctrine called the "right of publicity." But the exact scope of the right of publicity varies from jurisdiction to jurisdiction.


walking at a park
...
invading my privacy?

There is no privacy in a public park.

I'm 17 years old. Someone 33

The ages do not change it: there is nothing directly sexual about seeing and photographing people in a public park, and there is nothing to consent to.
When you venture out to a public place, you voluntarily make yourself visible to the public. Everyone can look at you and take pictures/videos. Depending on the jurisdiction, there may be rules with regards to whether you are the main feature in those pics/videos, or just happen to be in the frame. If you happen to be in such a jurisdiction, you may have a case for a civil legal action. But certainly no criminal charges.

Depends very much on where this happened.
germany
There is §23 KunstUrhG allowing pictures where the person is incidental to the location or event, subject to a balancing between the interests of the artist and the subject. Advertising use has special rules.
